# Flutter convert UTF-8 characters HTTP post

Tags: http, flutter, dart, http-headers, httpresponse

I have an issue trying to send UTF-8 characters in HTTP post request. Basically when i'm sending chinese/japanese characters the text will become gibberish. The text did get through and i received some response. Same goes if i inserted some emojis. I am posting this to some website.

I am using default http library and testing against this text:

卯鵜はございますが

Expectation:

卯鵜はございますが

What is shown on the website:

å¯éµœã¯ã”ã–ã„ã¾ã™ãŒ

When I submit the same text via the website, apparently it is encoding the utf8 characters before sending to the server. Not sure if i have to encode it first, but then I dont know how to achieve this result.

Here's how it looks like:

0A%u536F%u9D5C%u306F%u3054%u3056%u3044%u307E%u3059%u304C%0A%0A

**My code:**

```
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
         "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36",
         "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
       };


Map<String, String> body = {
         'message': '卯鵜はございますが',
         'securitytoken': someSecurityToken,
         'do':'updatepost'
       };

 var response = await http.post(someURL, headers: requestHeaders, body: body, encoding: Encoding.getByName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: You need to decode the UTF in server side.

Comment: I see, thanks...but unfortunately i don't own the server nor the website. I'm just a third party client. I tried using utf8 encoding library but the body request expects a string instead of List<Int>

Answer (score 0):

Special characters in HTTP payloads are commonly encoded in UTF-8 format. The encoding should be resolved on the server-side, not on the front-end(Flutter app).